# Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize bluetooth beatspill

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have turned on Bluetooth (and as visible) on Ubuntu 14.04 but it does not recognize any devices, but keeps on searching. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: What does `lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; uname -a;` reveal?